# How to get to a t variable from linear regression

Tags: regression

I know this must be standard material, but I had difficulty in finding a proof in this form.

Let $e$ be a standard white Gaussian vector of size $N$.  Let all the other matrices in the following be constant.

Let $v = Xy + e$, where $X$ is an $N\times L$ matrix and $y$ is an $N\times 1$ vector, and let

$$\left\{\begin{align}
\bar y &= (X^TX)^{-1}X^Tv\\
\bar e &= v - X\bar y
\end{align}\right.\quad.$$

If $c$ is any constant vector, $J = N - \mathrm{rank}(X)$, and

$$\left\{\begin{align}
u &= c^T\bar y\\
s^2 &= \bar e^T\bar ec^T(X^TX)^{-1}c
\end{align}\right.\quad,$$

then the random variable defined as $t = u/\sqrt{s^2/J}$ follows a normalized Student's T distribution with J degrees of freedom.

I would be grateful if you could provide an outline for its proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with the distribution of $\bar{y}$, show that since $v$ is normal, $\bar{y}$ is multivariate normal and that consequently $u$ must also be a multivariate normal; also show that the covariance matrix of $\bar{y}$ is of the form $\sigma^2\cdot(X^T X)^{-1}$ and thus -- if $\sigma^2$ were known -- the variance of $u$ would be $\sigma^2 c^T (X^T X)^{-1} c$.  Show that the distribution of $\bar{e}^T  \bar{e}$ must be chi-squared and (*carefully*) find the degrees of freedom.  Think about how what the operation $\bar{e}^T \bar{e} c^T (X^T X)^{-1} c$ must therefore produce, and what it's distribution and degrees of freedom are.

The result follows (almost) immediately from the definition of the t-distribution.